# SQL JDBC java commits when auto-commit is off

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

My intention is to try out SQL Rollback with the program exit halfway without finishing.I had the following connection in my program. However data still written to the database even when I did not set any con.commit upon exiting halfway. I did a debug mode, it fall into the exception and execute the con.rollback(); but in which is did not rollback. Which made me quite confuse.

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection(value);
con.setAutoCommit(false);
try{
pstmt = con.prepareStatement("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Test (Number varchar(255))")
pstmt.execute();
pstmt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO `Test` (Number) values (?)");
pstmt.setString(1,"1");
pstmt.executeUpdate();
}catch(Exception){
con.rollback();
}
```

Comment: sorry I dun get it? Can you provide some example ?

Comment: Your code does not seem complete. The insert statement can never be run it will throw a syntax error. This means there will be no work done. How can data still be written. And this seems like a snippet of a bigger function/procedure. Could you show us a little more code.

Comment: ok the code i given just now is a draft , if u want a complete statement,  i just added.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on DB, e.g. in Oracle Create table ... or any DDL execute implicit commit, all operations before this commit cannot be rollbacked

Comment: its not oracle its mysql which i tagged

Comment: What about insert statement ?